# Configure Alfresco 5.x with Apache httpd webserver with proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, tomcat7, alfresco

I have Alfresco 5.x enterprise. I want to have httpd web server ahead of actual Tomcat of Alfresco.

Do anyone have step by step guide to configure Apache httpd (I'm new to it). Help to configure Apache httpd with Tomcat. Proxy way is prefered.

Comment: This is rather too broad for Stack Overflow. People will be happy to help you, but it is important for you to show some research and effort first. What has your extensive web-searching turned up already? Is Alfresco running already? If so, what proxy configuration do you plan to use? Have you looked at mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http?

Comment: Follow the alfresco docs eg http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/tasks/configure-ssl-prod.html ?